# alias "nautilus $(pwd)" does not open in pwd directory

Tags: command-line, bash, nautilus, alias

I am using nautilus file manager and created the file `~/.bash_aliases` with the line

```
alias naut="nautilus $(pwd) >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown;"
```

Then I execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then when I type the command `naut`, the file manager does not open in the `pwd` directory but in the directory in which I last executed `source ~/.bashrc` . Which is weird, because when I create an alias

```
alias naut="pwd; nautilus $(pwd) > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown;"
```

the command `naut` always returns my actual working directory, while opening nautilus in another directory.

How is this possible?

Comment: It is quite clear: `$(pwd)` is expanded at the time the `alias` command containing it is run. Try enclosing the alias in single, instead of double, quotes.

Comment: Or just use `nautilus .`

Answer (score 3):

`man bash`:

> Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of
>          all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``,  `\`,  and,
>          when  history  expansion  is enabled, `!`.  The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain
>          their special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains  its
>          special  meaning only when followed by one of the following characters:
>          `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted  within  double
>          quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion
>          will be performed unless an `!`  appearing in double  quotes  is  escaped
>          using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.

As a consequence, in your definition `$(pwd)` is expanded when the alias is defined, not when it is executed. Use single quotes around the right-hand side of the alias definition.

On the other hand, as Bharadwaj Raju observes, the current working directory is always `.`, so `nautilus "$(pwd)"` is the same as `nautilus .`. And you probably want doublequotes around `$(pwd)`.